# How to write stream to S3 with year, month and day of the day when records were received?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple streams that reads some data from a Kafka topic:

```
 val ds = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1")
      .option("subscribe", "topic1")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()

val df = ds.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")
      .select(from_json($"json", schema).as("data"))
      .select("data.*")
```

I want to store this data in S3 based on the day it's received, so something like:

```
s3_bucket/year/month/day/data.json
```

When I want to write the data I do:

```
df.writeStream
  .format("json")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("path", s3_path)
  .start()
```

But if I do this I get to only specify one path. Is there a way to change the s3 path dynamically based on the date?

Comment: If you will partition by time, consider how you'll query. The problem with the usual year, month, day path nesting is that it makes certain types of queries quite difficult. It is usually preferable to partition along a single axis, e.g., s3_bucket/table_name/ts=yyyymmddhhmm/*.json, which allows for fast range queries. See https://spark-summit.org/east-2017/events/bulletproof-jobs-patterns-for-large-scale-spark-processing/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `partitionBy` clause:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(
    dayofmonth(current_date()) as "day",
    month(current_date()) as "month",
    year(current_date()) as "year",
    $"*")
  .writeStream
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
  ... // all other options
```